# How to print output data created by QDebug in a widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to programming. Would like to know how to print the output data from the code below (C++) using the Qt. I need an answer to appear in the `QTextEdit` window.

```
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++);
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post since people have taken time to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might capture the `qDebug` messages in a `QAbstractItemModel` or `QTextDocument`. Both of those classes are models, their associated views are `QListView` (or any other view), and `QTextEdit` (preferably `QPlainTextEdit` or `QTextBrowser`), respectively.

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qdebug-window-output-52061269
#include <QtWidgets>

struct LogToModelData {
   bool installed;
   QtMessageHandler previous = {};
   QList<QPointer<QObject>> models;
};
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(LogToModelData, logToModelData)

void logToModelHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context,
                       const QString &msg) {
   for (auto m : qAsConst(logToModelData->models)) {
      if (auto model = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemModel *>(m)) {
         auto row = model->rowCount();
         model->insertRow(row);
         model->setData(model->index(row, 0), msg);
      } else if (auto doc = qobject_cast<QTextDocument *>(m)) {
         QTextCursor cur(doc);
         cur.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
         if (cur.position() != 0) cur.insertBlock();
         cur.insertText(msg);
      }
   }
   if (logToModelData->previous) logToModelData->previous(type, context, msg);
}

void logToModel(QObject *model) {
   logToModelData->models.append(QPointer<QObject>(model));
   if (!logToModelData->installed) {
      logToModelData->previous = qInstallMessageHandler(logToModelHandler);
      logToModelData->installed = true;
   }
}

void rescrollToBottom(QAbstractScrollArea *view) {
   static const char kViewAtBottom[] = "viewAtBottom";
   auto *scrollBar = view->verticalScrollBar();
   Q_ASSERT(scrollBar);
   auto rescroller = [scrollBar]() mutable {
      if (scrollBar->property(kViewAtBottom).isNull())
         scrollBar->setProperty(kViewAtBottom, true);
      auto const atBottom = scrollBar->property(kViewAtBottom).toBool();
      if (atBottom) scrollBar->setValue(scrollBar->maximum());
   };
   QObject::connect(scrollBar, &QAbstractSlider::rangeChanged, view, rescroller,
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
   QObject::connect(scrollBar, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged, view, [scrollBar] {
      auto const atBottom = scrollBar->value() == scrollBar->maximum();
      scrollBar->setProperty(kViewAtBottom, atBottom);
   });
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget ui;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
   QListView view;
   QTextBrowser browser;
   layout.addWidget(new QLabel(QLatin1String(view.metaObject()->className())));
   layout.addWidget(&view);
   layout.addWidget(new QLabel(QLatin1String(browser.metaObject()->className())));
   layout.addWidget(&browser);
   QStringListModel model;
   view.setModel(&model);

   logToModel(view.model());
   logToModel(browser.document());
   rescrollToBottom(&view);
   rescrollToBottom(&browser);

   QTimer timer;
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [] {
      static int n;
      qDebug() << "Tick" << ++n;
   });

   timer.start(500);
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Also note that the separate declaration of the loop induction variable `i` is a very much obsolete C-ism - the last time you had to write code like that was two decades ago.

Comment: @Richard In a nutshell: Use `qDebug` as you would. To show the output, use a `QListView` with a `QStringListModel` or a `QTextBrowser` (or a `QPlainTextEdit`), then call `logToModel` on the model used by the view widget (recall that Qt editors use the `document()` i.e. `QTextDocument` as a model!). That's all. I demonstrate both an item model and a document model approach since `QListView` will be much faster once the log becomes long (thousands of lines).