# How to automatically keep a QTextEdit, QAbstractItemView, QAbstractScrollArea etc. scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: qt, scroll, qtextedit

An oft-sought behavior is to keep a "log" output widget scrolled to the bottom if the user hadn't scrolled elsewhere. There are widget-specific solutions out there, i.e. specific to `QTextEdit` or `QListView` etc., but they always require changes to user code - and the user code already does the right thing and appends the data to the model used by the view. Altering that code would unduly tie it to the particulars of the view, and thus has a bad software design smell.

What one might wish for, thus, is a way of modifying the behavior of the widget itself, without changes to user code. Furthermore - perhaps there's a way that would work in most any class derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`?

Answer (score 2):

A workable solution needs only to access the view's scrollbar, and can be easily adapted to work with any widget that uses a scrollbar - not only a `QAbstractScrollArea`, even though all vertically scrolling widgets that Qt provides do indeed derive from this widget (as they should!).

The key observation that allows such a low level approach is that whenever content is appended to the widget, the *range* of the vertical scrollbar will change. Thus:

1. Whenever the scrollbar's **`range`** changes, we scroll to the bottom iff we are in the `viewAtBottom` state.
2. Whenever the scrollbar's **`value`** changes, we update the `viewAtBottom` to reflect whether the scrollbar is at the end (maximum) of its range or not.

This allows the user to freely scroll within the contents without interference, but a scrollbar will "stick" at the end of the range when placed there.

One wishes of course that there was a way to imbue a `QScrollBar` with that behavior, but there's no flag that would enable it - at least as of Qt 5.11.

The following function, when called on a `QAbstractScrollArea` (i.e. any of the item views like `QListView` or `QListWidget`, a `QTextEdit`, `QTextBrowser`, `QPlainTextEdit`, etc), will imbue it with the behavior of staying at the bottom when content is added and the range of the scrollbar grows.

The below works in Qt 5, and can be trivially adapted to Qt 4 be reimplementing lambdas as slots in a helper class. A function taking a scrollbar directly can also be factored out.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qdebug-window-output-52061269
[...]
void rescrollToBottom(QAbstractScrollArea *view) {
   static const char kViewAtBottom[] = "viewAtBottom";
   auto *scrollBar = view->verticalScrollBar();
   Q_ASSERT(scrollBar);
   auto rescroller = [scrollBar]() mutable {
      if (scrollBar->property(kViewAtBottom).isNull())
         scrollBar->setProperty(kViewAtBottom, true);
      auto const atBottom = scrollBar->property(kViewAtBottom).toBool();
      if (atBottom) scrollBar->setValue(scrollBar->maximum());
   };
   QObject::connect(scrollBar, &QAbstractSlider::rangeChanged, view, rescroller,
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
   QObject::connect(scrollBar, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged, view, [scrollBar] {
      auto const atBottom = scrollBar->value() == scrollBar->maximum();
      scrollBar->setProperty(kViewAtBottom, atBottom);
   });
}
```

For a complete example of this code in action, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52061437/1329652).